# Transparent rect in view controller

Tags: ios, ipad, interface-builder, cgrect

I want to achieve an affect similar to a round html form with a transparent background similar to the image below (not the mouseover text, just the rectangle in the background, and have it have an opacity).

I do not know how to do this and I've toyed around with `CGRect` but I can't even get them to come up. I'm using the tab navigation based template for the iPad.

Could you please point me to some resources that could get me started with `CGRect`?

[image]

Comment: round html form means what?  .... did u mean rounded corner ?

Comment: something like this:
http://tylergaw.com/articles/assets/post_image_htmlFormErrors_defaultChrome.jpg

obviously without the mouseover text, and the white background needs to have some opacity.

Comment: hey that is UIPopupController.... do u want that ?....   https://www.dropbox.com/tray_login?i=325207631&t=1347525642&v=9b81fcf81d8fd01d3554006fac40bc9748c8a7b9&url=c%2Fshmodel%3Fsjid%3D70038198958712%26path%3D%252Fimg.png%26state%3D1%26id%3Dshmodel%26nsid%3D167262840&cl=en_US

Comment: error creating link! Do I really need a UIPopupController? Because it doesn't need to "pop-up"... I was just thinking UIButtons superimposed on a cgrect or in worse case scenario a png...but I'd love to try your method!....

Comment: hi sorry man... please see that link : https://www.dropbox.com/s/8ro0d1fd8odio99/img.png any doubt means feel free to ask man...

Comment: ah... actually No, that is the only part I dont want! that's the part I meant was mouseover

Comment: basically I want everything besides that popup, just the two UITextFields on top of a rectangle that has some opacity with rounded corners... but thanks for the knowledge about UIPopupController because I'm sure I'll need it later!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16677/discussion-between-spynet-and-user1392515)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Note** I'm going to make the assumption you're after the grey background rectangle behind the two form fields. Not the blue border around the email field. I'm assuming you want to achieve something similar to this:

[image: iPad Screenshot]

You need to create custom UIView subclass that either contains or sits directly behind your form fields and buttons. Depending on the complexity of your gradient and corner radius you can achieve a similar effect one of two ways.

#### 1. Using CALayer's `cornerRadius` and `borderColor` and `borderWidth`

A simple implementation of this view could be:

```
#import "RoundedView.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation RoundedView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
  if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    self.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor];
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
  }
  return self;
}

@end
```

#### 2. Overriding `drawRect:` to draw rounded corners

You'll be using `UIBezierPath` to draw a rect with rounded corners, fill it and stroke it.

```
@implementation DrawnBackgroundView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
  if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
  }
  return self;
}


- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
  CGFloat lineWidth = 2;
  CGFloat selfWidth = self.bounds.size.width - (lineWidth * 2);
  CGFloat selfHeight = self.bounds.size.height - (lineWidth * 2);

  UIColor* lightGray = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.84 green: 0.84 blue: 0.84 alpha: 1];

  UIBezierPath* roundedRectanglePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: CGRectMake(lineWidth, lineWidth, selfWidth, selfHeight) cornerRadius: 10];
  [lightGray setFill];
  [roundedRectanglePath fill];

  [lightGray setStroke];
  roundedRectanglePath.lineWidth = lineWidth;
  [roundedRectanglePath stroke];
}

@end
```

The screen shot above is taken from a quick demo project that is [available on GitHub](https://github.com/jessedc/RoundedBackgroundView).

Comment: wow... I'm speechless. thx so much! I'll implement it when I'm at my computer.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with a View-based template, create a project named Drawer. Add a UIView class to your project. Name it SquareView (.h and .m).

Double-click DrawerViewController.xib to open it in Interface Builder. Change the generic view there to SquareView in the Identity Inspector (command-4) using the Class popup menu. Save and go back to Xcode.

Put this code in the drawRect: method of your SquareView.m file to draw a large, crooked, empty yellow rectangle and a small, green, transparent square:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect;
{   
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); 
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0); // yellow line

    CGContextBeginPath(context);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 50.0, 50.0); //start point
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 250.0, 100.0);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 250.0, 350.0);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 50.0, 350.0); // end path

    CGContextClosePath(context); // close path

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 8.0); // this is set from now on until you explicitly change it

    CGContextStrokePath(context); // do actual stroking

CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.5); // green color, half transparent
CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(20.0, 250.0, 128.0, 128.0)); // a square at the bottom left-hand corner
}
```

You don't have to call this method for the drawing to happen. Your view controller will tell the view to draw itself at least once when the program launches and the NIB files are activated.